# Leaving USA to go to Brazil. Also have Irish Passport which doesn't need a visa for Brazil

Tags: air-travel, tickets, paperwork, dual-nationality, brazil

Airline ticket was booked with USA Passport.
Brazil requires Visa for USA Citizens.
I have an Irish Passport.
Irish Citizens do not need Visas to visit Brazil.
How does USA Airline handle that?
Do I show USA Passport to verify ticket, then show Irish Passport to show I can get into Brazil without a Visa?
And if that is how it works, how does USA Airlines know that an Irish Passport does not need a Visa to enter Brazil?
Lastly, and maybe not important, does Brazil see that I flew in from USA and booked ticket with USA passport?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I show USA Passport to verify ticket, then show Irish Passport to show I can get into Brazil without a Visa?

Exactly.

> How does USA Airlines know that an Irish Passport does not need a Visa to enter Brazil?

The TIMATIC database.

> Does Brazil see that I flew in from USA and booked ticket with USA passport?

No, nor do they care. You only show your (Irish) passport at Brazilian border control anyway.

Comment: @johnon123 If this answers your question, please accept it (button below the down arrow) and upvote it (up arrow)

Comment: Thank you for Answer!!  Let me ask you this, could I have booked my USA Airline ticket with my Irish Passport? And then upon return, showed Irish passport to verify ticket and USA passport (presumably USA Airlines check) to get into USA? If this would work, does USA take note I have an Irish Passport thus flagging me or putting me on some sort of IRS watch?

Comment: @johnon123 Border control has nothing to do with the ticket. At Brazilian border control (entry and exit), you show your Irish passport, and at US border control (entry only), you show your US passport. When checking in for the flight back to the US at the airport in Brazil, show your US passport

Comment: thanks again Coke! And it doesn't matter at all that I am a resident of USA?

Comment: @johnon123 No..